# How do I hide the navigation bar with hidesOnSwipe for a tableview not directly under the nav bar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

Here's my setup

Navigation Bar

UIView

UITableView

I'm using iOS 8's hidesOnSwipe property to hide the navigation bar when I swipe the tableview. The Navigation Bar hides when I scroll down, but it wont reveal itself when I scroll up unless I scroll the UIView above the TableView.

The hidesOnSwipe works fine when I use it in a Table View Controller
Is there anyway to solve this? I need to have an accessory view between the navigation bar and the tableView.

Comment: Is the view controller imbedded in a nav controller?

Comment: hey did you solve this? Having a similar issue here!